# how to Center icon in rows using ui element

Tags: html, css, element-ui

how can i center this edit icon even when one address string is longer than the other?

[image]

This is the column I'm having this problem

```
 <el-table-column
        prop="address"
        label="Address">
         <template slot-scope="scope">
              {{scope.row.address}}
              <el-button
                type="primary"
                icon="el-icon-edit"
                circle
                size="mini"
                style="margin-left: 55px"
                @click="open(scope.$index, scope.row)"
              ></el-button>
            </template>
      </el-table-column>
```

Here is the complete code:

https://jsfiddle.net/xhbzpvas/

Comment: Why not put the icon in its own table cell? https://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/tLq2deu1/3/

Comment: I tried that, but i get to much space between the icon and the strings (in my case is numbers). https://pasteboard.co/Jde8AtjT.png

Comment: As you are using numbers (according to screenshot), use `align="right"` on the `el-table-column`. Also the numbers are aligned in a better way, of cours you have to decrease the `margin-left` on the butten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="display: flex">
  <address style="flex-grow: 1"/>
  <icon/>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Flexbox (link below) is a set of gridding properties you can use in CSS. `flex-grow` is a property which allows the cell of a flex row to grow relative to other cells.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Please add **all** explanation to your answer by editing it